# Cross-browser method to clear content selection before dragging

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

Been trying to work through the various cross browser issues involved in clearing a content selection immediately before performing an HTML5 drag.

Current progress is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kamelkev/36ek328t/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var down = 0;

  $(document.body).on('dragstart.draggable', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).attr('draggable')) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    return;
  });

  $('div[draggable]').on('dragstart', function(event) {
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", '');
  });

  $('div[draggable]').on('mousedown.selections', function(event) {
    down = 1;

    return true;
  });

  $('div[draggable]').on('mouseup.selections', function(event) {
    down = 0;

    return true;
  });

  $('div[draggable]').on('mousemove.selections', function(event) {
    var doc = event.target.ownerDocument;

    if (down) {
      if (doc.selection) {
        doc.selection.empty();
      }
      else if (doc.getSelection) {
        if (doc.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
          doc.getSelection().empty();
        }
        else if (doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
          doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
      }

      down = 0;
    }
    else {
      down = 0;
    }

    return true;
  });
});
```

In Chrome/Safari/Firefox you'll notice that selecting all (<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>) the content and performing a drag on "thing2" will not only clear the selection, but allow the drag event to proceed. For some reason IE clears the selection, but then seemingly cancels the subsequent `dragstart` event.

I can find literally zero references to this type of behavior either within Microsoft's own documentation, or elsewhere. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

I've tried quite a few things to work around this problem, moving my various selection clearing code into different events, etc, but no luck.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I'm specifically doing this to avoid drag image issues when performing an HTML5 drag. The "ghost" image that you see when performing an HTML5 drag is generated from the sum parts of all the dragged content rather than from the element being dragged. If a user happens to do a select-all then the subsequently generated drag image will use all the content for the ghost image rather than just the content of the element being dragged. A non-issue for Firefox/Safari/Chrome as you have the ability to set a custom drag image, but for IE there are few alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a viable workaround after trying a large number of event permutations.

The clearing of selections within the IE mousemove handler seemingly prevents the dragStart event from ever firing. This is (as per usual) inconsistent with what other browsers do. However I discovered that clearing the selection within the dragStart handler sort of works as expected as long as you don't deal with iframes. If you're dealing with iframes I think mousedown is the only viable event you can work with.

However the other browsers are not behaving as one would expect either, as clearing a selection within a dragstart handler seemingly prevents the expected dragmove event from firing.

The solution is to handle selection clearing within the dragstart handler for all IE browsers, and doing so in the mousemove handler for all other browsers.